# Angular ng-repeat doesn't select bound value

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a key field that should be selected into a SELECT html element. This SELECT is populated with an *ng-repeat*.

I define two SELECTs, one with ng-repeat, other with ng-options:

```
<div ng-controller="MyDisplayCtrl">
    <select ng-model="context.id1">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option ng-repeat="i in lista" value="{{i.id}}">{{i.value}}</option>
    </select> Should have "three" selected, but shows - <br/>

    <select ng-model="context.id2" ng-options="i.value for i in lista">
    </select> Selects "three" automatically <br/>
</div>
```

And my controller goes like this:

```
function MyDisplayCtrl($scope) {
    var x1 = {id: 1, value: 'one'};
    var x2 = {id: 2, value: 'two'};
    var x3 = {id: 3, value: 'three'};
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.lista = [x1, x2, x3];
        });
    }, 2000);

    $scope.context = {id1: 3, id2: x3};
}
```

I'd have this list brought to client by an AJAX, so I used a *setTimeout()* here.

The approach with ng-options works, but I wouldn't have an object, sole its key.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nCG2H/

Problem: I'm trying to understand why the first SELECT doesn't work, algo because I got it to work depending on timing from AJAX response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use ng-selected="{{i.id}}" instead of value="{{i.id}}"...